# Generate bytecode from .class file Error

Tags: python-2.7, bytecode, traceback, windowserror

I've been trying to generate a bytecode from a class file via
Python27 and whenever I enter the full path of the .class file I always get this error:

[image]

Comment: For future reference, please post the error directly instead of taking a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Based on matching up the stacktrace with [the github repo](https://github.com/injectnique/KnuckleHeadedMcSpazatron/blob/master/BytecodeDisassembler.py), it looks like the line where you're getting the error is

```
Bytecode = subprocess.Popen(['javap', '-c', Java_Class],\
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

So Windows can't find javap. Can you make sure that you have the jdk installed? What happens when you try to run it on the command line?

Also, please post the text of the error instead of a screenshot.